# The PHP code I constructed is not working for all scenarios, what is wrong with it?

Tags: php

I am trying to solve the following:

Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

Note: sequence a0, a1, ..., an is considered to be a strictly increasing if a0 < a1 < ... < an. Sequence containing only one element is also considered to be strictly increasing.

Example

For sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false.

There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

For sequence = [1, 3, 2], the output should be
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true.

You can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, you can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

Below is my code:

```
function almostIncreasingSequence($sequence) {
    $count = count($sequence);
    $oldSeq = $sequence;
    sort($sequence);
    $key = 0;
    foreach ($oldSeq as $s) {
        $seq = $oldSeq;
        unset($seq[$key]);
        $changed_sec = $seq;
        sort($seq);
        if ($seq==$changed_sec) {
            $unique = array_unique($seq);
            if ($seq!=$unique) {
                $key++;
                if ($key==$count) {
                    return false;
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                return true; 
                break;
            }
        } else {
            $key++;
            if ($key==$count) {
                return false;
            }
            continue;
        }
    } 
}
```

Note that I am VERY beginner in programming in general, and I am aware that there are definitely shorter and simpler ways to get it right than using my code. I'd appreciate any notes on the easier and simpler ways to achieve the same, however my main focus is on what is wrong with the current code that I created.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: FYI: You can remove the `continue` and `break` keywords since you already use `return`. Because `return` will exit the function. Hence, the `break` is unreachable. The `continue` is the default behavior in your case (after the if-else there is no more code, so the `for`loop will just continue anyway)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the issue in your code is the array equality.

In order to 2 arrays to be considered equal in PHP, both of the arrays should have the same keys and values.

However, in your code, you're using `unset`, which **does not** reset the array's keys. For example:

```
php > $a = [1,2,3];
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
php > unset($a[0]);
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

So if you have a variable `$b = [ 2, 3 ]`, then `$a == $b` would be `false`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use `array_values`, which resets an array's indexes.

So, going back to the array `$a` from before:

```
php > print_r($a);
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
php > print_r(array_values($a));
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

So now, if you have `$b = [ 2, 3 ]`, then `array_values($a) == $b` would be `true`.

Comment: @cccc_wwww_cccc, I am glad that I was able to help! Please consider marking this answer as the accepted answer.